# Ident connection fails via psycopg2 but works via command line

Tags: python, postgresql, authentication, psycopg2

When I try to connect to my postgres server via psycopg2 with a bit of code like this (running python as "username"):

```
psycopg2.connect(database="apis_master")
```

I get an error

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "username"
```

But when I run psql straight from the command line (as user "username") like so:

```
psql -d apis_master
```

I connect with no problem.

I can't see what is different between these two connection methods. Am I missing some configuration option with psycopg2?

Answer (score 2):

Your command line user and your python user *are* different. When you instantiate psycopg2 object, pass user credentials:

```
db = psycopg2.connect(
                     host = 192.168.0.1, # example IP, use 'localhost' if local, otherwise the IP of the server where Postgre is located.
                     database = 'apis_master'
                     user = 'my_db_user',
                     password = 'my_db_password'
                     )
```

This should solve your connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were two PGSQL instances running on this system. One was 8.4 and not configured to ident with my username, the other was 9.1 and had my username. Command line psql was automatically picking 9.1 running on a non-standard port while psycopg2 was using the default port. Specifying the port in the psycopg2 connection line fixed the problem.